# Resources are deleted during solution retraction

Tags: 2010, retraction

I have a solution deployed in several web applications. If I retract it from one of them, resources from the */wpresources/* folder will be deleted, although there are web applications that still need it.
Does anyone have information about this issue? Is it fixable or not?

P.S. I use SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to: [SharePoint v3 Localized Resources](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michael_yeager/archive/2008/02/05/sharepoint-v3-localized-resources.aspx)

> If the assembly is deployed to the GAC, then the folder structure
>   containing the web parts resources will be in the virtual *wpresources
>   folder and the folders will be named as follows:
>   /*/ This
>   folder is physically located in this global location: C:\Program
>   Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\wpresources

vs.

> If the web part assembly is deployed to the Web Application’s bin
>   folder, then the web part’s resources will be in the physical
>   wpresources folder (no underscore) in a sub-folder named after the
>   AssemblyName.

So if you have single solution deployed on multiple web applications you need to put your assemblies into Web Application BIN (it makes sense). GAC vs BIN is always about permissions (didn't find any articles on using resources).

Alternatively you can always re-deploy solution on some other web application an you will have your resources back.

Comment: Yes, alternative way fixes the problem, but I want to make it work without this workaround. Anyway, thank you. I'll try use the informaion you gave me.